# Audit table and trigger

Tags: mysql, sql

In the **Classic Models database**, create a trigger on the **employees** table that places the details of any deleted employee into a separate audit table. You must also create this audit table. Be sure to delete at least two employees when testing to ensure that the trigger functions.

**Classic Models database** for the table `employees`:

```
/*Table structure for table `employees` */

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `employees`;

CREATE TABLE `employees` (
  `employeeNumber` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `lastName` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `firstName` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `extension` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `officeCode` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `reportsTo` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `jobTitle` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`employeeNumber`),
  KEY `reportsTo` (`reportsTo`),
  KEY `officeCode` (`officeCode`),
  CONSTRAINT `employees_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`reportsTo`) REFERENCES `employees` (`employeeNumber`),
  CONSTRAINT `employees_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`officeCode`) REFERENCES `offices` (`officeCode`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

/*Data for the table `employees` */

insert  into `employees`(`employeeNumber`,`lastName`,`firstName`,`extension`,`email`,`officeCode`,`reportsTo`,`jobTitle`) values 

(1002,'Murphy','Diane','x5800','dmurphy@classicmodelcars.com','1',NULL,'President'),

(1056,'Patterson','Mary','x4611','mpatterso@classicmodelcars.com','1',1002,'VP Sales');
```

Below is the code that I've created so far:

```
#Table

CREATE TABLE `sampleTrigger`(
  `employeeNumber` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `lastName` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `firstName` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `extension` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `officeCode` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `reportsTo` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `jobTitle` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`employeeNumber`)
);


#Trigger

DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER `employeesTrigger`
AFTER DELETE ON `employees`
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
INSERT INTO `sampleTrigger`
SET

`employeeNumber` = OLD.`employeeNumber`,
`lastName` = OLD.`lastName`,
`firstName` = OLD.`firstName`,
`extension` = OLD.`extension`,
`email` = OLD.`email`,
`officeCode` = OLD.`officeCode`,
`reportsTo` = OLD.`reportsTo`,
`jobTitle` = OLD.`jobTitle`;
    
END;
END $$
DELIMITER
;
```

When I ran my code, I got this error:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'END' at line 18
```

My question: I was able to create a table named sampleTrigger but the trigger has not been created. How should I create the trigger that works well?

Comment: #1. *the details of any **deleted** employee* but *BEFORE **UPDATE** ON*. #2. Separate assignments in SET are delimited with a comma. #3. SET itself must be terminated with semicolon. #4. `END IF;` without `IF`. PS. You forget to save deletion datetime.

Comment: @Akina Thanks for your comment. I edited my code. For the deletion datetime, can you please elaborate on which how to save the deletion datetime?

Comment: *how to save the deletion datetime?* Add autoutilized DATETIME column into your table. And do not asssign it.

Comment: *I got this error* `END; END $$` First finalizes BEGIN... what should do the second?

Answer (score 0):

You have shown some efforts,but since this is your homework, I would not spoil the fun of finding the errors. Here is a working one for you with minimum comment given, with regard to Akina's datetime remark.

```
use testdb;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `employees`;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `offices`;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `sampleTrigger`;
CREATE TABLE `offices` (`officeCode` varchar(10) primary key); 
CREATE TABLE `employees` (
  `employeeNumber` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `lastName` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `firstName` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `extension` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `officeCode` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `reportsTo` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `jobTitle` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`employeeNumber`),
  KEY `reportsTo` (`reportsTo`),
  KEY `officeCode` (`officeCode`),
  CONSTRAINT `employees_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`reportsTo`) REFERENCES `employees` (`employeeNumber`),
  CONSTRAINT `employees_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`officeCode`) REFERENCES `offices` (`officeCode`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

insert into offices values(1);
insert  into `employees`(`employeeNumber`,`lastName`,`firstName`,`extension`,`email`,`officeCode`,`reportsTo`,`jobTitle`) values 
(1002,'Murphy','Diane','x5800','dmurphy@classicmodelcars.com','1',NULL,'President'),
(1056,'Patterson','Mary','x4611','mpatterso@classicmodelcars.com','1',1002,'VP Sales');

CREATE TABLE `sampleTrigger`(
  `employeeNumber` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `lastName` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `firstName` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `extension` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `officeCode` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `reportsTo` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `jobTitle` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `deletetime` timestamp, -- here is the datetime suggested by Akina
  PRIMARY KEY (`employeeNumber`) -- you don't really need to make it a PK,otherwise you won't be able to reuse the deleted employeeNumber
);



DELIMITER $$
DROP TRIGGER if exists `employeesTrigger`$$
CREATE TRIGGER `employeesTrigger`
AFTER DELETE ON `employees`
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
INSERT INTO `sampleTrigger` values (
OLD.`employeeNumber`,
OLD.`lastName`,
OLD.`firstName`,
OLD.`extension`,
OLD.`email`,
OLD.`officeCode`,
OLD.`reportsTo`,
OLD.`jobTitle`,
default); -- leaving the timestamp to its default value
    
-- END; -- This one is excessive
END $$
DELIMITER ;


delete from employees where employeenumber=1056; -- make sure you delete the 1056 one first to avoid a constraint error
delete from employees where employeenumber=1002;

-- check the result set 
select * from sampleTrigger;
```

Comment: I will try to fix some errors. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! I was finally able to make it work!!!!!